# knockout js nested models with inherited data

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, coding-style

I'm making knockout js models. Ideally I would like to have subviews for each page. The model would look something like this:

```
function viewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.people = ko.observableArray([{"name":"Alice", parent:"Bill"},{"name":"Bill":"parent":"Candy"},{"name":"Candy","parent":""}]);

    function kidsModel()
    {
         var self = this;
         self.kids = ko.utils.arrayFilter(people, function(person) {
              return person.parent != "";
          }); 
    }

    function parentsModel()
    {
         var self = this;
         self.parents = ko.utils.arrayFilter(
                            ko.utils.arrayMap(people, function(person){
                                return person.parent;
                           })
                        , function(person) {
                              return person.parent != "";
                        });
    }
}
```

The key components are that I can segment the code with subviews and share data that is filtered through the root view. I have found plenty of info on setting things up in knockout with nice subviews but not about filtering data between them in a way that leverages knockout.

Comment: It's not very clear on what is the question. What is the issue you're struggling with?

Comment: I want to have a central observable array of data in the root view and share it with the child views in a way that, if something gets changed anywhere in the heierarchy it will bubble up to the root copy of the data and down to all it's childern. For example if something in the kidsModel changes the name or adds a kid it should reflect in the viewModel and in the parentModel. Does that help clear it up?

Comment: Does this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iluzyanin/uknutca1/) looks something like you're looking for? I moved child view models outside of main view model so you could put them in separate files.

Comment: Nice one! Write it up and I'll mark as a solution. Also why do you need the line: `self.templateData(undefined);` in the showKids/showParents methods?

Comment: Sure. That line was to make templates work smoothly - I had a condition to not render template, if it's data is `undefined`. I've updated the solution to include `isReady()` boolean flag for clarity. Now when `isReady()` is false, template is not rendered and you can change template's name and model without any issues (otherwise it would rase an error when you've changed name, but haven't yet changed the data). After switching is done, you set `isReady()` to true and KO renders template as it should. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by passing your `observableArray` as a parameter to child view models. For example (it's a little too much code, but it's pretty simple):

```
// Person model
function Person(name, parent) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.parent = ko.observable(parent);
}
// Template model, for sub views
function Template(name, data, isReady) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.data = ko.observable(data);
    this.isReady = ko.observable(isReady);
}
// Main view model, controls templates
function ViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.people = ko.observableArray([new Person("Alice", "Bill"), new Person("Bill","Candy"),new Person("Candy", "")]);

    // working with templates
    self.template = new Template('kidsTemplate', new KidsModel(self.people), true);

    self.showKids = function() {
        self.template.isReady(false);
        self.template.name('kidsTemplate');
        self.template.data(new KidsModel(self.people));
        self.template.isReady(true);
    };
    self.showParents = function() {
        self.template.isReady(false);
        self.template.name('parentsTemplate');
        self.template.data(new ParentsModel(self.people));
        self.template.isReady(true);
    };
}
// Sub-view model for Kids, takes observable array as a parameter
function KidsModel(people)
{
    var self = this;
    self.kids = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(people(), function(person) {
            return person.parent() !== "";
        });
    });
    self.newKidName = ko.observable('John');
    self.newKidParentName = ko.observable('Peter');
    self.addKid = function() {
        people.push(new Person(self.newKidName(), self.newKidParentName()));
    };
}
// Sub-view model for Parents, takes observable array as a parameter
function ParentsModel(people)
{
    var self = this;
    self.parents = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(
            ko.utils.arrayMap(people(), function(person){
                return person.parent();
            }),
            function(person) {
                return person;
                //return person.parent !== "";
            });
    });
}
```

And the markup is like this:

```
<button data-bind="click: showKids">Show kids</button>
<button data-bind="click: showParents">Show parents</button>
<div data-bind="template: { name: template.name, data: template.data, if: template.isReady}"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="kidsTemplate">
    <!-- ko foreach: kids -->
    <div>
        Kid's Name: <b data-bind="text: name"></b>, Kid's Parent: <b data-bind="text: parent"></b>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <div>
        New kid name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: newKidName" />, parent name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: newKidParentName" />
        <button data-bind="click: addKid">Add kid</button>
    </div>    
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="parentsTemplate">
    <!-- ko foreach: parents -->
    <div>
        Parent's Name: <b data-bind="text: $data"></b>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

#### [Working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/uknutca1/)